# How to assign a mocked interface to a property with a private setter for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, moq, mef

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(MyAbstractClass))
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    [Import] protected IFoo Foo { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (Foo == null) throw new Exception();

        var = Foo.GetBar();
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Basically, I use MEF to export classes out and get "common" imports. When I want to test these classes I can create mock interfaces of IFoo, but how do I actually get it in there with the private setter? MEF somehow is able to handle it, and I'm not sure how else I can test my DoSomething method.

Comment: is `IFoo` an optional dependency or do you always need it?

Comment: It is required (hence the MEF Import).

Comment: You can use  `[ImportingConstructor]` in MEF to use constructor injection - that would allow you to pass in a mocked interface as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this with the MS Moles framework:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Comment: Moles is definitely a great way of handling this.

Comment: I like the description of what Moles says, but I do wonder if it's the "right" way to handle this. I'm thinking maybe the right way might be to do the ImportingConstructor thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve your MEF Imports, the easiest way to do so is to use the `ImportingConstructorAttribute` instead of `ImportAttribute`s on each property.

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(MyAbstractClass))
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    protected MyAbstractClass(IFoo foo)
    {
        //BONUS! Null check here instead...
        if (foo == null) throw new NullArgumentException("foo");

        Foo = foo;
    }

    protected IFoo Foo { get; private set; }
}

public sealed MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyClass(IFoo foo) : base(foo) { }

public void DoSomething()
{
    var = Foo.GetBar();
    //etc.
}
```

}

The solution kind of stinks because now you have to have all classes that extend from MyAbstractClass each use an `ImportingConstructorAttribute` and call `base()`. This can get quite ugly if your abstract class is used all over and especially if it decides to add another imported property... now you have to change the constructor signature.

I'd stick with ugly reflection... better ugly unit tests than ugly code.

Comment: I disagree with your last comment. There is a dependency on `IFoo` and it should be made explicit. Additional, test code should be well-written code too.

Comment: I guess it's just a preference, but I prefer my "dependencies" to be visible via an `ImportAttribute` instead of a `ImportingConstructor`.

Comment: @m-y The problem with Property dependencies, is that they don't express the actual *required* state of a class. Using Constructor injection (`[ImportingConstructor]`) it allows you to create your class in such a way that it cannot have an invalid state. If you were to give your code to another developer, would it be easier for them to assume the class is usable after construction using property or constructor injection?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott: Wouldn't this concern have come up when the MEF team was implementing a way to mark fields/properties with `Import`? I guess, if that's the case then what is the point of `Import` for fields/properties?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`MyAbstractClass` has a dependency on `IFoo` but you're not making it explicit. You should add a constructor to make the dependency explicit:

```
public MyAbstractClass(IFoo foo) { this.Foo = foo; }
```

Now you can easily test it using your mock.

So, I'd rewrite your class like this:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(MyAbstractClass))
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    private readonly IFoo foo;
    public IFoo Foo {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IFoo>() != null);  
            return this.foo;
        }
    }

    protected MyAbstractClass(IFoo foo) {
        Contract.Requires(foo != null);
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyClass(IFoo foo) : base(foo) { }
}
```

Otherwise, you have to use reflection to get at the private setter. That's disgusting.

Comment: @m-y: I don't think that's correct. Can you explain why you think that? He can just mark the constructor with `ImportingConstructor` and remove the `Import` attribute.

Comment: @m-y: Sorry. However, just as I should have elaborated on that point in my initial post, you should have elaborated on the same in your comment. I'm not sure what makes you think that, but you can have a public constructor on an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

reflection is the best way to do it.  i like to create an extension method in a base test assembly with useful functions like accessing/setting private members and such.

another option (if it is acceptable to make the setter protected instead of private - which may or may not be the case here, but if you do have a protected member with a similar desire) would be have your test subclass the class under test.  it feels dirty and doesn't seem like a good idea, but i can't think of a practical reason why it's bad and would accomplish the objective here.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static T GetPrivateFieldValue<T>(this object instance, string fieldName)
    {
        var field = instance.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (field != null)
        {
            return (T) field.GetValue(instance);
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("The field specified could not be located.", "fieldName");
    }

    public static void SetReadonlyProperty(this object instance, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(instance, value, null);
    }

    public static void SetStaticReadonlyProperty(this Type type, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        type.GetProperty(propertyName).GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(null, new[] { value });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do share these extension methods :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public MyClass (IFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}
```

and change the "private set" in your abstract class to "protected set".

Comment: That would ruin his MEF Import.